# How to echo custom function

Tags: php, function, echo

i have this function

```
function getServerTitle() {
        return($this->_values[$this->_indexes["SERVERTITLE"][0]]["value"]);
    }
```

And i wanted to echo it, but it doesn't work.

```
echo getServerTitle();
```

It shows

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function getServerTitle()
```

Comment: It seems like it's a method of some class. Call it on an instance of whatever the class is.

Comment: don't copy and paste code, especially if you not know how it works

Answer (score 3):

Since the body of the function contains references to `$this`, it is not a function in the older sense of the word, but a non-static method on a class.

This implies, that the only way to run it in a meaningfull way is to instantiate the class and call the method of the resulting object.

e.g.

```
$object=new YOUR_CLASS_NAME();
echo $object->getServerTitle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Eugen's post is accurate; however, the specific error message you are getting usually comes up when PHP can't find the function you are trying to call.

Are your echo statement and function definition in separate files? If so, are you including the file that defines the function?

Comment: I assume it can't find the function because there is no global function called `getServerTitle`, only a method of some particular class.

Comment: Ok, never mind. I will use another script for get Shoutcast stats :) Thanks all for help!

Comment: @user2021811 Don't give up so easily! There is nothing wrong with the function, you just need to learn how to call it correctly.

Comment: I just used another php script and it works great! :) Thanks again for help!